# What output will echo > produce?

Tags: bash

I don't have a linux at hand and instead use compileonline.com to check out some code in bash, yet I'm new to bash. Could somebody give a hand?

```
for var
do echo $var > fniz
  cat fniz
done
```

arguments are 123 abc xyz

My guess is, the output would be:

```
123
123
abc
123
abc
xyz
```

But I'm not sure, whether echo $var > fniz overwrites fniz or writes a new line to it. Does it overwrite the file?

Comment: Please check the manual about redirections: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: > redirects. >> appends.

Comment: note that `bash` has a `noclobber` option which, if set, prevents you from overwriting an existing file (i.e. the second and further `echo`s would fail) in which case you would have to use `>!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` always overwrites.

Writing a new line would be achieved by using the “append” redirection operator `>>`.

Comment: `>` doesnt *always* overwrite, namely if `set -o noclobber` is in effect. Then it will refuse to clobber an existing file.

Comment: @hyde: I accept your comment, but maintain my answer as appropriate for the level of bash the OP is in.

Comment: Well, I'd avoid using word "always" when it's inaccurate, because such strong statements can get stuck into memory of a reader who does not know better, especially if it is an upvoted answer. I'd phrase it something like "always tries to overwrite" or "always overwrites (or fails trying)" or I'd add a footnote with more details.

Comment: A counterargument (today is futile debate day here): `>` always overwrites because when `noclobber` hits, the entire command is void so there is no `>`.

Answer (score 2):

It overwrites the file each time

```
$ cat script.sh 
for var in 123 abv xyz
do
    echo $var > fniz
    cat fniz
done
$ ./script.sh 
123
abv
xyz
```

If you want to append, use `>>`

Comment: Nope. As you've written it, the output will be just “xyz”, since you're clobbering the file each time.

Comment: @Emmet True. But notice that we call `cat fniz` in the loop, so it prints all three values. The contents of the file after the execution will indeed be `xyz`

Comment: ah, right. I misinterpreted the intention of your example. My bad.